# UWP Server Socket not listening

Tags: windows, uwp, c++-cli, win-universal-app

I am creating a simple UWP console server app with reference to the contents of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets#build-a-basic-tcp-socket-client-and-server) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/StreamSocket/cpp/Scenario1.xaml.cpp) links.

However, if i create code based on the examples and run it, I will not be able to connect to the server. Also, the port is not open when checked with a command such as "netstat -na".

Does anyone know how to solve it?

The code is shown below. I would appreciate if you find any errors in the code below.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Platform;
using namespace Concurrency;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Networking;
using namespace Windows::Networking::Sockets;
using namespace Windows::Networking::Connectivity;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;

namespace SocketTest {
    public ref class Server sealed {
        public:
            Server();
            void Run();
        protected:
            void Server::onConnReceived(
                Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListener^ listener,
                Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^ object);
    };
}

using namespace SocketTest;

Server::Server() {
}

void Server::onConnReceived(
    StreamSocketListener^ listener,
    StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^ object)
{
    try {
        DataReader^ reader = ref new DataReader(object->Socket->InputStream);
        //ReceiveStringLoop(reader, object->Socket);
        delete object->Socket;
    }
    catch (Exception^ exception) {
        std::cout << "onconnection error" << std::endl;
    }
}

void Server::Run() {
    StreamSocketListener^ listener = ref new StreamSocketListener();
    listener->ConnectionReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListener^, Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs^>(this, &Server::onConnReceived);
    listener->Control->KeepAlive = true;

    create_task(listener->BindServiceNameAsync(L"12345")).then(
        [=]
    {
        try
        {
            std::cout << "Listening ..." << std::endl;
        }
        catch (Exception^ exception)
        {
            std::cout << "Bind error" << exception->Message->Data() << std::endl;
        }
    });
}

int main(Platform::Array<Platform::String^>^ args)
{
    Server^ s = ref new Server();
    s->Run();
    getchar();
}
```

Or, if you have a better code example, let me know.

Comment: Your code snippet may not be able to reproduce the issue. Did you get any exceptions? Did you get "Listening" output? Is your UWP app converted from win32? By the way, what's your client side app? Are the client and server on same machine?

Comment: I got a "listening" output and saw no exceptions appear. The client-side app was simply checked locally using netcat, but before that it was verified through the "netstat -na" command that the port was not open.

Comment: The uwp app was created from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp), not from win32.

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Also, the privateNetworkClientServer and internetClientServer permissions are properly set.

Comment: Could you please also try to test the client side on another device?  What's the result you are getting  from the netcat tool you mentioned if you run the official sample server side?